# Perl Foreach until loop

Tags: perl

I have output that looks something like this:

```
Id: 214215
Time: 5:07
jName:  Bar_Start
joutcome:  warning
pName:  Bar
jstatus: running
 stepName Start:
   outcome: success
   status: completed
---End Step---
 stepName A:
   outcome: success
   status: completed
---End Step---
 stepName B:
   outcome: success
   status: completed
---End Step---
 stepName C:
   outcome: success
   status: completed
---End Step---
 stepName DC:
   outcome: warning
   status: completed
---End Step---
---------------END FINAL---------------
Id: 123456
Time: 11:08
jName:  Foo_Start
joutcome:  success
pName:  Foo
jstatus: completed
 stepName A:
   outcome: success
   status: completed
---End Step---
 stepName AD:
   outcome: success
   status: completed
---End Step---
```

I would like to parse it out so that each line before the "---End Step---" *including the header* is stored in a hash like:

```
  my %rowdata = (
    Id            => "214215",
    Time          => "5:07",
    jName         => "Bar_start",
    jOutcome      => "warning",
    pName         => "Bar",
    jStatus       => "running",
    stepName      => "Start",
    outcome       => "success",
    status        => "completed",
  );

  my %rowdata = (
    Id            => "214215",
    Time          => "5:07",
    jName         => "Bar_start",
    jOutcome      => "warning",
    pName         => "Bar",
    jStatus       => "running",
    stepName      => "A",
    outcome       => "success",
    status        => "completed",
  );

  my %rowdata = (
    Id            => "214215",
    Time          => "5:07",
    jName         => "Bar_start",
    jOutcome      => "warning",
    pName         => "Bar",
    jStatus       => "running",
    stepName      => "B",
    outcome       => "success",
    status        => "completed",
  );

...

  my %rowdata = (
    Id            => "123456",
    Time          => "11:08",
    jName         => "Foo_start",
    jOutcome      => "success",
    pName         => "Foo",
    jStatus       => "completed",
    stepName      => "A",
    outcome       => "success",
    status        => "completed",
  );
```

I believe I need to do something like the following to populate my hash:

```
foreach my $key (keys %rowdata) {
        if ($row =~ m/\s*$key:.*/) {
          $rowdata{$key} = $row;
        }
      }
```

But I'm not sure how to separate the header with one step and then include a new header when you get to ---END FINAL---

Then i would like to iterate through each stored hash and do stuff based on the present conditions. Currently the output is stored in an array (@rows)

Comment: Please show an example of the actual hash you want to generate for the sample data, instead of using `""` as placeholders. In your input, each `jName` seems to have multiple corresponding `stepName` blocks, so would the `stepName` field in your hash contain an array?

Comment: No, there should be one jName and one stepName per hash. So there would be x number of hashes for x number of stepNames before ---End Final---

Comment: Edited what the hashes should look like

Comment: Thanks for editing, your question is much clearer now. Instead of multiple hashes, I would recommend using one hash with the "header" information at the top level and the step-specific information in an array, e.g. `%data = ( Id => "214215", Time => "5:07", jName => "Bar_start", steps => [ { stepName => "Start", status => ... }, { stepName => "A", status => ... }, ... ] );`

Comment: hmm that is interesting. That may work, but I will need to be able to iteratively go through each stepname with its corresponding outcome and status and run condition statements on it. Is that possible to do?

Comment: It is certainly possible. Another possibility, if `stepName`s are unique within a `jName` block, is a hash of hashes, e.g. `%data = ( ..., steps => { Start => { status => ... }, A => { status ... } } );` Data is much easier to work with when you choose a suitable data structure to hold it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to keep just the *latest* value of each parameter, and save a set of values to a list on each occurrence of `---End Step---`.

This program does exactly that. I have used [`Data::Dump`](https://metacpan.org/module/Data::Dump) only to demonstrate that the resultant data structure is as requested.

**Note that** your last output record reflects the contents of the penultimate input record. I have used your sample data to generate the output shown here.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open my $fh, '<', 'data.txt' or die $!;

my (@data, %rowdata);

while (<$fh>) {
  if ( /^\s*(\w+) \s* : \s* (.*\S) /x or / \b (stepName) \s* (\w+) : /x ) {
    $rowdata{$1} = $2;
  }
  elsif ( /---End Step---/ ) {
    push @data, { %rowdata };
  }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \@data;
```

**output**

```
[
  {
    Id       => 214215,
    jName    => "Bar_Start",
    joutcome => "warning",
    jstatus  => "running",
    outcome  => "success",
    pName    => "Bar",
    status   => "completed",
    stepName => "Start",
    Time     => "5:07",
  },
  {
    Id       => 214215,
    jName    => "Bar_Start",
    joutcome => "warning",
    jstatus  => "running",
    outcome  => "success",
    pName    => "Bar",
    status   => "completed",
    stepName => "A",
    Time     => "5:07",
  },
  {
    Id       => 214215,
    jName    => "Bar_Start",
    joutcome => "warning",
    jstatus  => "running",
    outcome  => "success",
    pName    => "Bar",
    status   => "completed",
    stepName => "B",
    Time     => "5:07",
  },
  {
    Id       => 214215,
    jName    => "Bar_Start",
    joutcome => "warning",
    jstatus  => "running",
    outcome  => "success",
    pName    => "Bar",
    status   => "completed",
    stepName => "C",
    Time     => "5:07",
  },
  {
    Id       => 214215,
    jName    => "Bar_Start",
    joutcome => "warning",
    jstatus  => "running",
    outcome  => "warning",
    pName    => "Bar",
    status   => "completed",
    stepName => "DC",
    Time     => "5:07",
  },
  {
    Id       => 123456,
    jName    => "Foo_Start",
    joutcome => "success",
    jstatus  => "completed",
    outcome  => "success",
    pName    => "Foo",
    status   => "completed",
    stepName => "A",
    Time     => "11:08",
  },
  {
    Id       => 123456,
    jName    => "Foo_Start",
    joutcome => "success",
    jstatus  => "completed",
    outcome  => "success",
    pName    => "Foo",
    status   => "completed",
    stepName => "AD",
    Time     => "11:08",
  },
]
```

---

**Update**

```
What would be the appropriate call to an array such as this?

If I wanted to do a `foreach` loop of it, would it be something like

    foreach %key (@data) {
      if (key{jName} =~ Foo_start) {
         #then do this
      }
    }
```

I think I may have made a mistake by suggesting that you copy and store the contents of `%rowdata` on each occurrence of `---End Step---`. If all you need to do is to process the data sequentially, then you may be best served by writing `process_rowdata(\%rowdata)` instead of `push @data, { %rowdata }`.

However, the immediate answer to the question is that you could iterate over `@data` by using

```
for my $rowdata (@data) {
  next unless $rowdata->{jName} eq 'Foo_start';
  # Do stuff with $rowdata
}
```

But you haven't explained your purpose, and a loop like this is an inefficient way to select items from the list if you have to do it more than once or twice or the list is tiny.

Comment: I like this. What would be the appropriate call to an array such as this? If I wanted to do a foreach loop of it, would it be something like `foreach %key (@data) { if (key{jName} =~ Foo_start) { #then do this }}`

Comment: @EvanMiller: It appears that you are way beyond your depth with Perl. Stack Overflow has a primary goal of creating a treasury of solutions to the most common programming problems. Because of that it has become something of a forum where the very best of minds can discuss ideas and choose *best* solutions (which I believe is a good thing) and also a place where milkmaids come to get high-value consultancy for nothing. Where do you think you fall in all of this? If you are unable to write Perl code that iterates over an array of hash references, then perhaps you should pay for someone who can?

Comment: I completely disagree, as mentioned by stack exchange "Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers." While I agree that this is a wonderful place to discuss the best solutions to programming questions, this is also a place for people to _learn_ and expand their knowledge of new concepts and ideas, hense why it is in the question and answer format. I would say I am in the category of an enthusiastic programmer, who is new to some of these concepts but loves to learn.

Comment: That being said, I do appreciate the solution you gave me.

Comment: @EvanMiller: I am not surprised that you disagree with me, given that it disadvantages you. At the same time your must understand that I despise your use of Stack Overflow as a glorified and intelligent reference manual. [`perldoc.org`](http://perldoc.perl.org/) is extraordinary, and in many ways it is the best portal to access the standard documentation that accompanies every release of Perl.

Comment: @EvanMiller: If you ask a question here and get a solution, then you will learn very little and you will be the author of code that, while you may think you understand it, you wouldn't be able to reproduce. If you think of yourself as an "enthusiast programmer" then, please, write programs, and by all means ask for help if you are stuck. But what you are doing here isn't programming -- it's splicing and scrapbooking other people's software.

Comment: @Borodin You are right and I do agree that I wouldn't be able to reproduce it. I did attempt to write the program myself and find a solution (if you see my original question). The method did work but it seemed very sloppy to me and I wanted to find a better solution. But in the future, I will spend more time investigating instead of directly going to StackExchange. Thanks for your updated solution!